# Hidden optgroup dynamically after choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have 2 optgroup in my select list **(category and subcategory)**
 and i am trying to show optgroup and hide other on selection of subcategory.

for example if I choose in the category (sport, music) 
in the subcategory **I display only the sport and music**

I tried with the following code but it doesn't work

Thanks

```js
$("#custom_form_names_category").on("change", function() {
  var selectedVal = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
  console.log(selectedVal);
  $('#custom_form_names_subcategorie > [aria-label="' + selectedVal + '"]')
    .show()
    .siblings("optgroup")
    .css("display", "none");
});

$(".js-select2").select2({
  closeOnSelect: false,
  allowClear: true,
  tags: true,
  dropdownCssClass: "beforecheckbox"

});
```

```css
.select2.select2-container {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.select2-container .select2-selection__rendered {
  padding: 5px 15px 0 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-image: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--single {
  height: 100% !important;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
}

.beforecheckbox .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true]:before {
  content: "";
  color: #fff;
  background: url(../images/svg/check_active.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

.beforecheckbox .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true]:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
}

.beforecheckbox .select2-results__option[aria-selected=false]:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  border: #b7b9cc solid 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
}

.beforecheckbox .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true]:before {
  background: red;
}

#custom_form_names_category {
  margin-bottom: 50px !important;
}

.select2.select2-container {
  margin-bottom: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.full.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="custom_form_names_category" multiple class="js-select2 small-select addplaceholderslect select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <option value="1" data-select2-id="25">Sport</option>
  <option value="17" data-select2-id="26">Volley</option>
  <option value="18" data-select2-id="27">Musci</option>
  <option value="29" data-select2-id="28">film</option>
  <option value="35" data-select2-id="29">Englich</option>
</select>

<select id="custom_form_names_subcategorie" multiple class="js-select2 small-select addplaceholderslect select2-hidden-accessible">
  <optgroup label="Sport" data-select2-id="33">
    <option value="2" data-select2-id="34">Dance </option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Musci" data-select2-id="35">
    <option value="3" data-select2-id="36">Catégorie 4</option>
    <option value="4" data-select2-id="37">Rap</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Volley" data-select2-id="38">
    <option value="5" data-select2-id="39">Catégorie 4</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="film" data-select2-id="40">
    <option value="7" data-select2-id="41">Catégorie 5</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot interact with the option groups, You can only disable them, but with the rendered result of select2.

test:

```
$('#custom_form_names_subcategorie').on('select2:open', function (e) {
//var first = $('#custom_form_names_category').find(':selected');
//console.log(first);
setTimeout(function(){
    $('[aria-label]').hide();
    $('#custom_form_names_category').find(':selected').each(function( index ) {
        var selected = $( this ).text();
        console.log( index + ": " + selected );
        $('[aria-label="' + selected + '"]').show();
        console.log($('[aria-label="' + selected + '"]'));

    });
},100);
//$('[aria-label="' + selectedVal + '"]').show().siblings("li").css('display', 'none');
```

});

This also works when you select more than one. I had to put a setTimeout because in the on open event, of the version of select2 you used, in reality the select is not yet drawn. try to change version. However this works.

Alternatively you should fill the second select dynamically as defined in this link:
[Add, select, or clear items](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items)

Comment: I have tried it and it works. there is a space between $ and (did you remove it?

Comment: yes i tried in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/thomas_david88/9syuk0fj/30 but it's not work

Comment: can you check in jsfiddle

Comment: the problem is that the select is drawn when it opens. I tried with on select: open but still the elements are not detected.
I do other tests and answer you

Comment: please just lite problem
for example if I selected sport and I choose Music from category I will have in subcategory list of music and no sport